# Deform a plane with datas

Tags: three.js, 3d

For a dataviz project, I have some datas in an array. I need to use these datas to render a wave in ThreeJS like this:

[image]

The height of each peak depends on the given size and must be in its circle depending on the year.

I thought about creating a plan and deforming it with a vertex shader based on the data. Unfortunately, it seems that this is not possible. I'm a bit lost and I clearly need advices about how to do this.

The array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "year": 2016,
    "dimension": 28.400 // hectares
  },
  {
    "year": 1995,
    "dimension": 12.200
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-implement-heatmap/4007?u=prisoner849) will give you some ideas.

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "displacementMap" texture property on the THREE.Materials.. this will displace the vertices vertically based on the brightness of the pixel in the texture.

You can make a plane with a bunch of subdivisions, like new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10,  30,30),new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({displacementMap:yourDisplacementTexture})

For the displacementMap texture, you can either use an external image, or create a canvas, draw your height data into that, and then create a THREE.Texture( thecanvas ).

Yet another option is to create the subdivided plane using THREE.PlaneGeometry()

then get the geometry.vertices, and modify them by setting the .z value in each vertex.. followed up with geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true (to tell the renderer to send the modifications to the GPU).

Comment: Ok ! I'll try :)